# "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:" with autoComplete (special characters?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

jQuery  1.10.2 & jQuery ui core v1.11.4

I have these errors when I search a terme with AutoComplete :

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Lewis, George E.
>
> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: What?

I have also a lot of this when I navigate with my mouse on the results :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

This is the code :

```
function agostoAutocomplete(self){

// Recuperation de la page de recherche
var searchUrl = $(self).attr("data-search");
console.log(searchUrl);

//Création d'une fonction pour les catégories
$.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
   _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
       var that = this,
                  currentCategory = "";
       //Verifie si il y a une categorie
       $.each(items, function(index, item) {
            if(item.category){
                if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                   ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category MEDIA"+item.idrub+"'><h4>"+item.category+"</h4></li>");
                   currentCategory = item.category;
                   //alert(item.category);
               }
               that._renderItemData(ul, item);
            } else {
               that._renderItemData(ul, item);
               //alert('no category works!');
            }
        });
    }
});
//Lancement de la function créée
$(self).catcomplete({
    delay: 100,
    minLength: 1,
    source: searchUrl,
    autoFocus: true,
    response : function(event, ui) {
        // Test si resultat ou pas
        if (ui.content.length === 0) {
             var noResult = { 
             value: "", 
             label: "No results found" 
             };
             ui.content.push(noResult); 
        } else {
        }
    },
    }).data("custom-catcomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var noresult = $(item.label);
        console.log("label: "+item.label);
        console.log("category:"+item.category);
        console.log("idobject: "+item.idobject);
        console.log("idRub: "+item.idrub);
        console.log("reference: "+item.reference);
        console.log("value: "+item.value);
        console.log("CompositionObject: "+item.compositionobject);
        //var t = item.label.replace('.',"//.");
        if (item.label == 'No results found'){
            return $("<li class='ui-menu-item ui-no-result'><h4>"+item.label+"</h4></li>").appendTo(ul);
        } else {
            if (item.icon){
                return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                .append(
                    $("<a class='ui-menu-item autoAjax' data-id-object="+item.id+" data-id-rubrique="+item.idrub+" data-composition-object="+item.compositionobject+"></a>")
                    .append($("<img></img>").attr('src', item.icon))
                    .append( $("<h5>"+item.label+"</h5>")))
                    .appendTo(ul);
            } else {
                return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
                .append(
                    $("<a class='ui-menu-item autoAjax' data-id-object="+item.id+" data-id-rubrique="+item.idrub+" data-composition-object="+item.compositionobject+"></a>")
                    .append($("<img></img>").attr('src', "/plugins/spipr_agosto/img/nologo.png"))
                    .append($("<h5>"+item.label+"</h5>")))
                    .appendTo(ul);
            }
        }
};
```

}

For the other results, it's working like :

> jose, garcia

or

> robert, fatice

I've trying to found it several hours, but still no chance.. Do someone know where I'm wrong?

Here the snippet :

```js
// Initialisation de Autocomplete
function agostoAutocomplete(self){

 // Recuperation de la page de recherche
 
 //Création d'une fonction pour les catégories
 $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
       _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
           var that = this,
                currentCategory = "";
           //Verifie si il y a une categorie
           $.each(items, function(index, item) {
             if(item.category){
              if (item.category != currentCategory) {
                    ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category MEDIA"+item.idrub+"'><h4>"+item.category+"</h4></li>");
                    currentCategory = item.category;
                    //alert(item.category);
                }
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
             } else {
                that._renderItemData(ul, item);
                //alert('no category works!');
             }
           });
        }
 });
 //Lancement de la function créée
   var availableTags = [
      { label: "What?", category: "test1" },
      { label: "Lewis, George E.", category: "test2" },
      { label: "antal", category: "" },
      { label: "annhhx10", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annk K12", category: "Products" },
      { label: "annttop C13", category: "Products" },
      { label: "anders andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
      { label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
    ];
 $(self).catcomplete({
     delay: 100,
     minLength: 1,
     source: availableTags,
     autoFocus: true,
        response : function(event, ui) {
            // Test si resultat ou pas
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                 var noResult = { 
              value: "", 
              label: "No results found" 
           };
           ui.content.push(noResult); 
            } else {
            }
        },
  }).data("custom-catcomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
   var noresult = $(item.label);
   console.log("label: "+item.label);
   console.log("category:"+item.category);
   console.log("idobject: "+item.idobject);
   console.log("idRub: "+item.idrub);
   console.log("reference: "+item.reference);
   console.log("value: "+item.value);
   console.log("CompositionObject: "+item.compositionobject);
          //var t = item.label.replace('.',"//.");
   if (item.label == 'No results found'){
    return $("<li class='ui-menu-item ui-no-result'><h4>"+item.label+"</h4></li>").appendTo(ul);
   } else {
     if (item.icon){
     return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
     .append(
      $("<a class='ui-menu-item autoAjax' data-id-object="+item.id+" data-id-rubrique="+item.idrub+" data-composition-object="+item.compositionobject+"></a>")
      .append($("<img></img>").attr('src', item.icon))
      .append( $("<h5>"+item.label+"</h5>")))
      .appendTo(ul);
    } else {
     return $("<li></li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)
     .append(
      $("<a class='ui-menu-item autoAjax' data-id-object="+item.id+" data-id-rubrique="+item.idrub+" data-composition-object="+item.compositionobject+"></a>")
      .append($("<img></img>").attr('src', "/plugins/spipr_agosto/img/nologo.png"))
      .append($("<h5>"+item.label+"</h5>")))
      .appendTo(ul);
    }
   }
 };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="search" data-search="spip.php?page=autocomplete_center" placeholder="Type an artist name" id="recherche_media_resource" class="recherche" onfocus="agostoAutocomplete(this);" >
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just try with jquery-1.11.3, and I have the same problem..

Answer (score 1):

remove this line:

```
var noresult = $(item.label);
```

I'm not sure what it's good for, but it forces the error, because `item.label` will be used here as selector, but e.g. `Lewis, George E.` or `What?` are not valid selectors